# How to programmatically obtain openstack resource usage metrics from python?

Tags: python, openstack, collectd

As a non-admin user of open-stack, I do want to obtain how many vms our of the total quota are running at a specific time.

I do want to monitor usage of such resources by writing a collectd plugin for it.

I observed that there are already two types of collect plugins related to open-stack but none of seems seem to address this simple use case: a user that wants to monitor his own usage of these resources.

- [collectd-openstack](https://github.com/rochaporto/collectd-openstack) which seems not to be maintained and that seems to [require admin rights](https://github.com/rochaporto/collectd-openstack/issues/21), a deal-breaker limitation
- [collectd-ceilometer-plugin](https://github.com/openstack/collectd-ceilometer-plugin) which is mostly the oppisitve thing: feeding data captured by collectd to ceilometer.

I don't care about the state of the entire cloud, I am interested only about usage inside my project.

How API should I use in order to obtain this informations? Funny, most of the information I need is already published on the web dashboard. Still, I need to capture it with python/collect in order to send it to other systems for processing.

Answer (score 1):

You need use nova client API for that. Have a look at http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/api.html